# Python: os.path.isfile() in a if and combination gives an error

Tags: python, os.path

I would like to check if a date is greater than and if a file exists:

```
    if datetime.date(datetime.now()) >= get_expire_date() and os.path.isfile("hanso.txt") :
```

but it gives me an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hanso.txt'

Of course not found, that is what i want to check. Someone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: `isfile` returns `False` for cases like that. You have some other bug.

Comment: What about `os.path.exists`?

Comment: os.path.exists gives the same error

Comment: only with a if statement:  if os.path.isfile("hanso.txt"): it works fine.

Comment: Please add 2 _complete_ code snippets (no calls to functions that we can't see) reproducing both the scenario that works and the scenario that doesn't work. Odds are when you create these snippets you will solve it yourself :)

Comment: this alone works: if datetime.date(datetime.now()) >= get_expire_date(): 
this alone also works: if os.path.isfile("hanso.txt") :
together they dont work: if datetime.date(datetime.now()) >= get_expire_date() and os.path.isfile("hanso.txt") :

Comment: I don't know this function `get_expire_date()`. Please create 2 complete code snippets and add them to your starting post.

Answer (score -1):

I probably need to check if the file exists

```
file_path = "hanso.txt"

if os.path.exists(file_path):
   if datetime.date(datetime.now()) >= get_expire_date() and os.path.isfile(file_path) :
else:
    print("no such file or directory '{}'".format(file_path)
```

Comment: i need to check this together with the date. Only then the following code should proceed

Comment: It's up to you, you can check it with the date, or with two IF checks

Comment: you are right it works with 2 if statements, but it would be interesting to know why its not working within and if and construction. For me isfile() is to check if a file exists and it can be that it doest exist.

Comment: maybe you should do like this: if date_check and exists_check and isfile_check ?